# Erdos-Hajnal-like property for bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Erdos, Hajnal and Pach proved that for any finite graph $H$ (graph = undirected, no loop) there is a constant $\delta > 0$ such that for every finite $H$-free graph $G = (V,E)$ (i.e. $G$ does not contain any induced subgraph isomorphic to $H$) there exist $A,B \subseteq V$ such that $|A|,|B| \geq |V|^\delta$ and either $A \times B \subseteq E$ or $(A \times B) \cap E = \emptyset.$

I wonder if the same holds if one starts with a bipartite graph, that is:

For any finite bipartite graph $H$ there is a constant $\delta > 0$ such that for every finite $H$-free bipartite graph $G = (V,W,E)$ there exist $A \subseteq V$ and $B \subseteq W$ such that $|A|\geq |V|^\delta$, $|B| \geq |W|^\delta$ and either $A \times B \subseteq E$ or $(A \times B) \cap E = \emptyset.$

I tried but I wasn't able to deduce the latter from the former, since every bipartite graph $(V,W,E)$ has always large homogeneous sets in the sense of the first statement (e.g. suppose $|V| = |\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}| \geq |W|$, then $A = \{v_1, \ldots, v_{n/2}\}, B = \{v_{n/2},\ldots,v_n\}$ will do the job, if $n$ is even). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think a proof of your "bipartite Erdos-Hajnal" can be reached via ideas already known in literature, making it easier than the normal "Erdos-Hajnal", which is still a conjecture. I don't believe it is written down explicitly anywhere. We use a tool called the VC dimension. The definition and property of this could be found by googling.

Now, if you know the definition well enough, you could convince yourself that

**Proposition 1**: Assume the bipartite graph $G = (A, B, E)$ is $H$-free. Let $\mathscr{F} \subset 2^A$ be the set system $\{N_A(b): b \in B\}$, where $N_A(b)$ denote the neighbor of $b$ in $A$. Then $\mathscr{F}$ has VC dimension at most $|H|$.

We next note the following result of Sauer.

**Proposition 2**: If a set system $\mathscr{F} \subset 2^A$ on $A$ has VC dimension at most $d$, then it has size at most $(|A| + 1)^d$.

Now we are set to prove the "bipartite Erdos-Hajnal theorem".

**Proof**: Set $k = |H|$. Without loss of generality, assume the bipartite graph $G = (A, B, E)$ satisfies $|A| \leq |B|$, and both are sufficiently large relative to $|H|$. Take any subset $A' \subset A$ of size $|A|^{1 / 2k} - 1$. Apply Proposition 1 to the bipartite graph $(A', B, E)$. Then the set system $\mathscr{F} = \{N_{A'}(b): b \in B\}$ has VC dimension at most $k$. Apply Proposition 2, we find that $\mathscr{F}$ has size at most
$$(|A'| + 1)^{k} \leq |A|^{1/2}.$$
Thus, by the pigeonhole principle, we can find $B' \subset B$ of size at least $|B| / |A|^{1/2} \geq |B|^{1/2}$ that have the same neighbor in $A'$! Finally, this implies that we can find $A'' \subset A'$ of size at least $|A'| / 2$ that is either empty or complete to $B'$. qed.